# Get values from array of child objects in Golang with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am using the mgo.v2 driver with the latest version of MongoDB installed. My document structure is defined like this:

```
type gameTemplate struct {
ID       bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
GameCode string        `bson:"gamecode" json:"gamecode"`
Players  []player      `bson:"players" json:"players"`
}

type player struct {
PlayerID bson.ObjectId `bson:"playerid" json:"playerid"`
Username string        `bson:"username" json:"username"`
Level    int           `bson:"level" json:"level"`
}
```

How would I go about getting a list of usernames in a particular game (Defined by `gamecode`)?

Is there a way to get the size of the array and iterate through the elements, or is there a preferred method?

Comment: Are you getting the entire document from Mongo and working with it in Go? If so, it's just a slice, you use `len` and `range` like any other slice, there's nothing special about it.

Comment: New to working with Go and Mongo, so not sure if this answers your question, but I am directly interacting with the collection as a whole. I wasn't aware it was possible to interact with a document directly.

Comment: Not sure I understand - yes, it's possible to get documents out of the database, that's half of its purpose. Have you tried looking at some examples of working with Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could get all player with specific game code like this:

```
players := []gameTemplate{}
err = session.DB(DBname).C(Colloctionname).Find(bson.M{}).All(&players)
```

as you defined each players has username and size of players slice is the number of username which has specific game code.

---

ps:

be careful and change DBname and Colloctionname whit your Database and collection name and use session of your databse connection
be